# Commit doesn't happen

Tags: git, husky

I set up `husky` to do pre-commit formatting and run tests. When i do `git commit -m "readme fix"` I got this:

```
 PASS  src/App.test.jsx
  ✓ plug (15 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.91 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.

Watch Usage
 › Press a to run all tests.
 › Press f to run only failed tests.
 › Press q to quit watch mode.
 › Press p to filter by a filename regex pattern.
 › Press t to filter by a test name regex pattern.
 › Press Enter to trigger a test run.
```

But commit actually doesn't happen. And I can't do anything with the terminal? except Ctrl + C. Even when I try to input a, f, q and so on - nothing happens. How to actually make a commit? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: May you share the command that husky runs?

Comment: @evolutionxbox here is what husky runs: `lint-staged; npm test` And here is what `npm test` runs: `react-scripts test; echo test`

Answer (score 0):

The long list of "Press something..." messages says that the test runner didn't quit but it is waiting to do more things. Press `q`, it will exit and the commit will conclude.

Change the way to run the tests to not start it in the "watch" mode (you should probably remove `--watch` from its command line).

The output you posted looks similar to the output of `jest`. Take a look at the [Jest CLI options](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--watch).

The purpose of `--watch` or `--watchAll` is to run Jest in a TDD working style. After the initial execution of tests, it watches the test files and runs them as soon as they are modified. You do not care any more about running it, you just write the use cases and the code.
It is not appropriate for what you want.

---

Btw, running the tests or code linting or code beautifier or any other program that needs more than 0.5 seconds to complete is a bad idea. One of the key differences between Git and Subversion or other older CVS-es is that with Git the commits happen instantly. Committing in the Git philosophy is a smarter way of saving your work. You should commit often and the commit operation should not stay in your way. By adding lengthy operations as commit hooks you prevent yourself from using Git as it has been designed to be used.

Comment: I tried to press q, but nothing happens. Also I haven't specified anywhere --watch option and haevn't find it anywhere in my scripts